# Converting TIF to GeoTIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, google-maps, convert

I am using a function to download Google Maps images given a pair of latitude and longitude of the area. I can manage to change the format of the downloading images into JPEG or PNG or TIFF but I would like to save the images as GeoTIFF in order to keep the spatial information. I don't have a lot of experience on that so is there a way to do that? Like input the existing image and then input the format I want it to be converted.

Comment: You have corner coordinates? If so, you could use GDAL.GCP to georeference the image and save the output as a geotiff.

Comment: No I don't. But I guess I can get it if it makes it easier. What I have right now is given a pair of lat and lon and a zoom level it returns an image of the area but the format is either a jpeg or a tiff.  How gdal.gcp works? And is it possible to use it in Colab and not the terminal?

Comment: You would have to know the coordinates of at least two points on the image and the corresponding pixel coordinates on the image. Here is an example:  https://kokoalberti.com/articles/georeferencing-and-digitizing-old-maps-with-gdal/    Do you have gdal installed?  What happens when you run gdalinfo yourfilename.tif on of the output files?

Comment: I get this as an output:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF\nFiles: high_resolution_image.tif\nSize is 256, 256\nCoordinate System is `'\nImage Structure Metadata:\n  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL\nCorner Coordinates:\nUpper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)\nLower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)\nUpper Right (  256.0,    0.0)\nLower Right (  256.0,  256.0)\nCenter      (  128.0,  128.0)\nBand 1 Block=256x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red\nBand 2 Block=256x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green\nBand 3 Block=256x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue\n